# How to obtain the private key from the mnemonic phrase?

Tags: polkadot, key

I want to add my dot address to the trust wallet. For that I need the private key. How to transform the mnemonic to the private key.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/how-can-manually-generate-same-address-from-mnemonic-as-subkey-without-it